# Simulate Bivariate Beta Distribution , BIBETA(6, 20, 2) in R

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, beta-distribution, bivariate

I need to simulate bivariate beta distribution, $BIBETA(6, 20, 2)$ in `r`. I am looking for a package/ code that would generate bivariate beta distribution. I couldn't find the `r` function for this distribution.

The probability density function of the Bivariate beta distribution is given as below.

$$f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{B(a,b,c)} \dfrac{x^{a-1}y^{b-1}(1-x)^{b+c-1}(1-y)^{a+c-1}}{(1-xy)^{a+b+c}}$$
Is anyone know which `r` function can be used for this simulation?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52627286/1100107

Comment: An answer is contained here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315865/bivariate-beta-distribution

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `MultiRNG` that implements this sort of multivariate simulation for a wide class of multivariate distributions (in your particular case, you are interested in the `draw.dirichlet` function).

More interestingly, you could write your own function by implementing a very simple acceptance-rejection scheme (it is very similar to the univariate case). I remember reading the [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949658408810763?journalCode=gscs20) by Loukas some years ago which thoroughly showcases several options you could go for.

Comment: Do they have dirichlet cdf in `r`?

Comment: Probably [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/implementation-of-dirichlet-cdf) is what you are looking for, although in your question you asked for simulation!

Comment: I am trying to use the above function. I have `a <- c(6, 20,2)`. I generated x and y random variables using `draw.dirichlet`. Now what is t in the above function.  is t 2 by 2 matrix?

Comment: The `draw.dirichlet` implements a Dirichlet distribution, which is **NOT** the bivariate beta asked for.