# CDF of Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, integral, dirichlet-distribution

We know that a random variable $p=(p_{1}, p_{2},..., p_{K})$ which follows a $\textit{Dirichlet}$ distribution with parameters $\textbf{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2},..., a_{K})$ has as pdf

$$f(p) = \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\prod_{i=1}^{K}p_{i}^{a_{i}-1}$$

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution there is no CDF expression for the $\textit{Dirichlet}$ distribution and here https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-CDF-of-Dirichlet-Distribution, they note that the expression of CDF is really complicated and they redirect you to [Implementation of Dirichlet cdf?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/implementation-of-dirichlet-cdf) where they recommend using $\textit{Monte Carlo}$ approximation for the CDF.

---

Suppose that $K=3$, then I assume the CDF of the distribution for $\epsilon >0$ would be

$$F(\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(p\leq \epsilon ) = \mathbb{P}(\begin{bmatrix}p_{1}\\ p_{2}\\ p_{3} \end{bmatrix} 
\leq 
\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon\\  \epsilon\\ \epsilon 
\end{bmatrix}) = \mathbb{P}(p_{1}\leq \epsilon, p_{2}\leq \epsilon,p_{3}\leq \epsilon)= \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}p_{1}^{a_{1}-1}p_{2}^{a_{2}-1}p_{3}^{a_{3}-1}dp_{1}dp_{2}dp_{3} $$
$$=\frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\frac{\epsilon^{a_{1}}}{a_{1}}\frac{\epsilon^{a_{2}}}{a_{2}}\frac{\epsilon^{a_{3}}}{a_{3}}$$

I assume I do something totally wrong, because I do not take into account that $\sum_{i=1}^{K}p_{i}=1$. If I did then we would have to calculate the integral

$$\frac{\epsilon}{B(\textbf{a})}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\int_{0}^{\epsilon}p_{1}^{a_{1}-1}p_{2}^{a_{2}-1}(1-p_{1}-p_{2})^{a_{3}-1}dp_{1}dp_{2} $$

where I assume that this is the integral that it is very complicated to be solved. So, the only way to compute it is through numerical approximations as pointed out here [Implementation of Dirichlet cdf?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/implementation-of-dirichlet-cdf) ?

Comment: What is the cdf of a multivariate vector? Why is it of interest? The quantity you consider as $F(\epsilon)$ is not a multvariate cdf as $\epsilon\in\mathbb R$. It should be in $\mathbb R^3$. Or more specifically in the simplex of $\mathbb R^3$. And the pdf is incorrect as well, since it supported by the simplex of $\mathbb R^3$, hence is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure on that simplex, not $\mathbb R^3$. In simpler terms, there are two integrals, not three, since $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

Comment: @Xi'an follow the definition displayed on Wikipedia, that is for three random variables $X$ and $Y$ the the CDF is $F_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y, Z\leq z)$ where $F_{X,Y,Z}$ is the joint CDF. My ultimate goal is to prove the consistency of a Bayesian Model with Dirichlet prior and Multinomial Likelihood, like the question I posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250131/consistency-of-dirichlet-distribution. It is not of direct interest the calculation of the CDF, but I want to get more familiar with the DIrichlet distribution

Comment: The latter case where I rewrite the $p_{3}$ as $p_{3}=1-p_{1}-p_{2}$ then has to be the correct integration?

Comment: @Xi'an So, they have to be different because if they are all equal, I assume that we integrate on a region that is outside of the simplex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dirichlet distribution is either defined on the simplex of $\mathbb R^k$,
$$\mathcal S_{k-1}=\big\{\mathbf x;\ x_i\in (0,1),~i=1,2,\ldots,k,~\sum_{i=1}^k x_i=1\big\}$$
in which case the density
$$f(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_{i}^{a_{i}-1}$$
is with respect to the Lebesgue distribution over that simplex, or defined in $\mathbb R^{k-1}$, in which case the density
$$f(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}x_{i}^{a_{i}-1}(1-x_1-\cdots-x_{k-1})^{a_k-1}$$
is with respect to the Lebesgue distribution over $\mathbb R^{k-1}$.
The later is [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Probability_density_function) albeit poorly written since written as a function of $k$ terms.

A particular instance of the later is the family of [Beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), which illustrates why it is not feasible to derive an closed form cdf, except for small integer values of the parameters $a_i$:
$$\mathbb P_{\alpha,\beta}(X\le \epsilon)=\dfrac{B(\epsilon;\alpha,\beta)}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\quad0\le\epsilon\le 1$$
where $B(\epsilon;\alpha,\beta)$ is the so-called incomplete Beta function (and an acknowledgement of the absence of closed form!).

Both representations obviously lead to the same distribution, but writing events such as $\mathbb P(\mathbf X\in A)$ will depend on which representation is used for $A$, i.e., either $A\subset\mathcal S_{k-1}$ or $A\subset\mathbb R^{k-1}$. In the former case,
$$\mathbb P(\mathbf X\in A)=\int_A \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\prod_{i=1}^{k}x_{i}^{a_{i}-1}\,\text d\lambda_{\mathcal S_{k-1}}(\mathbf x)$$
and in the later
$$\mathbb P(\mathbf X\in A)=\int_A \frac{1}{B(\textbf{a})}\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}x_{i}^{a_{i}-1}(1-x_1-\cdots-x_{k-1})^{a_k-1}
\,\text dx_1\cdots\,\text dx_{k-1}$$

Comment: I see, so the problem was that I wasn't defining properly the densities and that the event that I was trying to calculate the probability wasn't restricted to the simples defined by either of the approaches